# Laravel 5.8: How to resolve auth()->user() inside Global Scope's apply method?

Tags: php, laravel, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, laravel-5.8

I need to apply specific global scope only if authenticated user's role is equal to something. So that user with certain role will only be able to execute queries on a given subset of records.

I can easily deal with User model (of currently logged in user) but not inside scope's apply method.

> https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22316#issuecomment-349548374
>
> **The scope constructor executes very early, before the auth middleware 
>   has run**. Resolve the user within the apply method, not in the constructor.

OK, so I'm inside the `apply` method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class UserScopeForSalesContactAdmin implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        dd('within apply', auth()->user());
        dd(auth()->user()); // won't work

        $builder->where('foo', '=', 'something from currently logged in user');
    }
}
```

Obviously second `dd` gives:

> Maximum function nesting level of '512' reached, aborting!

How to resolve this? I imagine I should call IOC container via `app()->make()` but then?

Thanks for any hints.

edit: I think I see what's causing the infinite loop (https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26113) but still I need to find a best way to obtain the User…

Comment: Have you tried the Auth::user()? If you can get the request into the scope, you could give a try to $request->user() too. Don't know about what is causing this, but maybe there is a conflict under the hood and using a workaround could make it.

I'm not sure, but I think Auth::user() do a query to the db every time you use it.

Answer (score 12):

The method what you are looking for is exactly **`Auth::hasUser()`**. The method was added in Laravel 5.6 through my PR.

[[5.6] Add ability to determine if the current user is ALREADY authenticated without triggering side effects by mpyw · Pull Request #24518 · laravel/framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/24518)

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class UserScopeForSalesContactAdmin implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        if (Auth::hasUser() && Auth::user()->role === 'something') {
            $builder->where('foo', '=', 'something from currently logged in user');
        }
    }
}
```

Just call `Auth::hasUser()` to prevent `Auth::user()` from causing side effects.

Comment: This is fantastic, I was just about to move this logic to controllers, but persevered with 'laravel MUST have an answer for this'.

Answer (score 2):

**Introduction**

Finally found a solution for this, I have been trying to fix it and looking for solutions for over an hour. The problem with what I have is that I am using a trait to apply the global scope on certain models and not all models. The list is big so I had to find a way to use `auth()->check()` in a global scope.

**Solution**

So in your model class or trait that is being used by your model class, you can listen to the `RouteMatched` event, which assures that the session provider is booted. Then add the global scope within the the event listener's closure/callable.

**Code**

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Events\RouteMatched;

/**
 * The "boot" method of the model.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected static function boot()
{
    Event::listen(RouteMatched::class, function () {
        static::addGlobalScope('company', function ($query) {
            // auth()->check() will now return the correct value
            // Logic here
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are defining a scope for User, while retrieving the user with Auth::user() it will utilize the scope again before it has been resolved the first method call and there from we have an StackOverflow. I think there is a clever approach, overwriting guards, and saving an user model on a class you can fetch out from there, but am also not a fan of tweaking with built in `Laravel` features.

An simple approach could be to utilise Auth::id and fetching out the info you need with DB::table, it's not pretty but i think it is a straight forward approach to solving the problem.

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    // this will not trigger the scope when you fetch it out again, and avoiding the stackoverflow
    $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', Auth::id())->get()->first();

    $builder->where('foo', '=', $user['the_answer_to_life']);
}
```

Comment: It's not often i write db::table logic it could be off a little, but i guess you get the point.

Comment: What you're saying makes absolute sense to me, unfortunately Auth::id() also throws "Maximum function nesting level of '512' reached, aborting!" even in dd(). I thought about putting data for scope into session variable but I'm not convince how solid that would be.

Comment: I will reproduce it on my local environtment at some point and figure out a solution when time is for it.

Comment: Thanks Martin, let me know if you've found something. For now as a workaround I went with sessions, but I'm I don't find this solution a stable one. :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by simply adding the user id to the session, right after successful login (Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php, attemptLogin()) :

```
$request->session()->put('id_user', $user->id);
```

...And then fetching it within the global scope like:

```
$id_user = (request()->session()->get('id_user')) ?? null;
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Mike. Utilizing session to solve my problem was my initial plan, but I don't want to rely on sessions at all in this case as it doesn't give me a feeling that this is a solid solution against the problem… Thank you anyway.